# PrimeVue. Как сделать так, чтобы текст в ячейках TreeTable оканчивался точками при переполнении ячейки

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, primevue

Существует ли способ автоматически "обрезать" текст в ячейках TreeTable компонента PrimeVue, чтобы он оканчивался на "..."?

Comment: Если вы хотите ответить на собственный вопрос (если я правильно вас понял), то разбейте вопрос на собственно вопрос и самоответ

Comment: @Глеб Сделал. Не знал, что так можно. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Способ заключается в пробрасывании TreeTable Pass Through аргументов в Column. А в частности аргументов в bodyCellContent.
Решение я также позаимствовал их этого [Поста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092374/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8)

```html
<TreeTable
  show-gridlines
  scrollable
  resizable-columns
  class="p-treetable-sm"
  :value="model"
  :removable-sort="true"
  :row-hover="true"
  column-resize-mode="expand"
  :auto-layout="true"
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
>
  <Column
    v-for="col in columns"
    sortable
    :expander="true ? col.key == '0' : false"
    :field="col.field"
    :header="col.label"
    :pt="{
      bodyCellContent: {
        style: {
          'overflow': 'hidden',
          'white-space': 'nowrap',
          'text-overflow': 'ellipsis'
        }
      }
    }"
  />
</TreeTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к ответу, объект `bodyCellContent` у свойства `pt` в компоненте `Column` принимает также функцию `filter` который можно применить чтобы ограничивать текст программно, вот пример:

```html
  <Column
    v-for="col in columns"
    sortable
    :expander="true ? col.key == '0' : false"
    :field="col.field"
    :header="col.label"
    :pt="{
      bodyCellContent: {
        style: {
          'overflow': 'hidden',
          'white-space': 'nowrap',
          'text-overflow': 'ellipsis'
        },
        filter: (value, rowData, column) => {
          // Обрезать текст, если он слишком длинный (например, до 20 символов)
          if (typeof value === 'string' && value.length > 20) {
            return value.slice(0, 20) + '...';
          }
          return value;
        }
      }
    }"
  />
```